# Beautify output of nested classes

Tags: php, loops, foreach, nested-class, bulletedlist

I am currently using a rather extensive API that changes on a regular basis. As I am constantly pulling the latest API specifications, I decided to dump all of the data to a page for easier viewing. As it stands now, I am just using `var_dump` but due to the length it can be pretty rough on the eyes.

As the data is essentially just nested classes, I would like to do the first level as roman numerals, second level as bullet points, third as alphabet, etc. Is there any easy simplistic approach to do this without just nesting dozens of foreach loops just to account for as many levels possible?

Example data:

```
object(stdClass)#58 (5) {
  ["MinecraftModule"]=>
  object(stdClass)#59 (24) {
    ["BukGetCategories"]=>
    object(stdClass)#60 (3) {
      ["Parameters"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["ReturnTypeName"]=>
      string(7) "JObject"
      ["IsComplexType"]=>
      bool(true)
    }
    ["BukGetPopularPlugins"]=>
    object(stdClass)#61 (3) {
      ["Parameters"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["ReturnTypeName"]=>
      string(7) "JObject"
      ["IsComplexType"]=>
      bool(true)
    }
    ["BukGetPluginsForCategory"]=>
    object(stdClass)#62 (3) {
      ["Parameters"]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#63 (2) {
          ["Name"]=>
          string(12) "CategoryName"
          ["TypeName"]=>
          string(6) "String"
        }
        [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#64 (2) {
          ["Name"]=>
          string(10) "StartIndex"
          ["TypeName"]=>
          string(5) "Int32"
        }
        [2]=>
        object(stdClass)#65 (2) {
          ["Name"]=>
          string(8) "PageSize"
          ["TypeName"]=>
          string(5) "Int32"
        }
      }
      ["ReturnTypeName"]=>
      string(7) "JObject"
      ["IsComplexType"]=>
      bool(true)
    }
```

Comment: Try using `print_r($var)` instead its a cleaner output IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to output an array or object with formatting:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($var);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: It definitely looks better with print_r over var_dump but its still not really what I am going for. I really want to break it down into lists / sub-lists to get a more clean overview of how it looks and quickly navigate through. With how long it is, both of these options are not working out as well.